# Disable specific scripts on mobile screen sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

My purpose is to achieve something like what you can do with CSS links, when you add *media* attribute and you can disable those CSS for a resolution of less than n pixels and still load them and use them.

What I'm trying to do is adapt a Joomla website into a mobile one using jQuery and Bootstrap, but some plugins call their own scripts and CSS files when they are inserted, and I can't change this behaviour, nor delete the scripts because client doesn´t want desktop layout to change. So for CSS i did this:

```
$(document).ready(function({
$('body').find('link').attr('media', 'screen and (min-width:969px)');
}));
```

This actually works perfect for CSS because it still loads, but doesn´t interfere with mobile layout that calls Bootstrap. So what comes next its try to do the same for scripts, I have tried this

```
$(document).ready(function({
$('body').find('script').each(function(){
   var screen = parseInt($(window).width());
      if(screen>==969){
      $(this).removeAttr('src');
      }
   });
}));
```

But it's not working, and this solution won't work either if screen size change, so am I missing something, or what could be the best approach? My intention is to target the body since here is where this inserted tags could appear. If I remove all script tags content for dekstop would not display properly. Is there something as the media attribute for script tags?

Comment: once a script is loaded, you can't unload it, and your `.ready()` wouldn't fire until AFTER all of the js code has been loaded anyways. Instead, you should **REVERSE** the logic. `if (screen < 969) { insert new script tag into dom }`

Comment: But I'm building scripts that target the same elements at responsive, but conflict with the scripts loaded with it. Its currently a Joomla website so many plugins work this way, how could I bypass them?

Comment: Let me just to make sure I understand what you are doing. You have a Joomla site that does not use bootstrap, but you are using bootstrap for smaller screens/mobile?

Comment: Client is running a Joomla 1.5 site, and won't update it because reasons, so I do this to insert Bootstrap CSS: `<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width:969px)> href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">` and added the media min for the existing CSS. The  proper way would be to implement Bootstrap for all screen sizes but client is hard and doesn't want to. So I have to deal with this rough bone

Comment: jquery and bootstrap.js are inserted the traditional way, even conflicting with MooTools, that is another question I have but if this could be done I could apply same logic on MooTools

Comment: If these are your scripts, let them load, but add the check inside them and let them execute only if screen size is what you want. `if(screenSize == whatYouWant){  /*... do something */ }`. You have resize events and the ability to check screen size in js.

Comment: I guess I'm just missing the reason why you are trying to insert all of these scripts instead of just modifying the CSS on the current site. It is possible to make a responsive website without bootstrap, and from the sounds of it, it'll be easier if you modify what you currently have instead of trying to put another layer on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

For the javascript you can use the mq function of Modernizr, this allows for you to programmatically check if the current browser window state matches a media query.

First you have to load modernizr.js

For example:
small = Modernizr.mq('only all and (max-width: 1200px)');
...
if(small){
    ...
 }

Comment: This approach could be useful, but unfortunately I can only use jQuery, or on worst cases MooTools (library I actually know nothing about)